# Get Flash CS4 Intellisense to recognize Objects on stage?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs4

When I create an object of a movieclip in code I get the flash intelesense to pop up in Flash CS4 Actions panel which is very helpful but if I simply place a moveclip on the stage then give it an object name in the options the Flash intelesense does not pop up in my code.

Anyway to get Flash intellisense to work with objects placed on the stage from the library?

Comment: "[IntelliSense](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense)" is a Microsoft product. You may name it "[Code completion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_code_completion)" instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the "code assist" function to popup in the flash IDE Action Panel you have two options:

- declare the variable of your object before make any reference to it, example:

> ```
> var clip:MovieClip;
> ```

then the code assist should popup anytime you write "clip."

- change you object instance name so it ends with "_mc". This would have the same result as the above but without declaring the variable.

I rather prefere the first solution, where you declare all your variables prior to writing any code.

Comment: If I end with _mc will I see the properties and methods in the movieclip?

Comment: in flash IDE, open the actionscript panel and type "clip_mc."
http://img521.imageshack.us/img521/1921/autocompletion.jpg

Comment: Dome is correct. Ideally, if you code a fair amount, do your code in an external application. Where the intellisense just works and it has a bunch of other neat things that make programming more admin free. I use FlashDevelop, it's free and I can vouch for its goodness.